# GCP: how to access proj-1 secret manager from proj-2 CloudBuild?

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-iam, google-secret-manager

All my GCP containers use `CloudBuild` on `my-dev-project` and access `secret manager` on the same project (`my-dev-project`). However, *one project requires access to `secrets manger` on `my-prod-project`*. I imagine I need to add a service account, but I'm not sure how I can go about doing that for `CloudBuild` when it already has it's `my-dev-project` service account.

**Question**: How can I access `my-prod-project` `secret manger` from the `my-dev-project` `CloudBuild`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant the Cloud Build service account from `my-dev-project` permissions on the secret in `my-prod-project`. Get the service account's email address from `my-dev-project` from the IAM console; it will be in the format:

```
project-number@@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
```

In `my-prod-project`, find the secret you wish to grant access, add that email with Secret Accessor permissions.

Comment: Thank you! I was a bit confused, I'll do this.